# Plotting points with OpenstreetMap in R

Tags: r, plot, openstreetmap

I tried to get Berlin map from `OpenStreetMap` and then plot some locations on it (they should look like points, not markers).

I got the map based on the data I have cause I don't want a whole map, but area where includes all locations. However when I plot the points on the map, it delivers an error message:

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(OpenStreetMap)

# creating a sample data.frame with lat/lon points

lon <- read.csv("Data.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses=c("NULL", "NULL", NA))
lat <- read.csv("Data.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses=c("NULL", NA, "NULL"))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))

# getting the map
mapberlin <- openmap(c(max(lat)+0.03,min(lon)-0.03), c(min(lat)-0.03,max(lon)+0.03), zoom = NULL,type = 'osm')

# plotting the map with some points on it and draw line between points
plot(mapberlin) +  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = 'red'), size = 2, shape = 21) 

+geom_line(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = 'blue') +

+guides(fill=FALSE, size=FALSE)
```

Comment: please read [how to write a great R question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126); share `dput(head(df))`

Comment: could you give the first few lines of `data.csv`?

Comment: id lat lon
A 52.49006 13.35491
B 52.49009 13.41953
C 52.4902 13.35637
D 52.51668 13.414048
Here is my few lines of data.